# How to save WPF user setting in XML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm a WPF newbie. I'm building a simple WPF app which require the user to login using the C# language. In the login page, user allow to tick on the "Remember me" and the "Sign me in automatically" check box but if the app closes, the setting will be reset to default. So, what I want is after every time the user ticks the checkbox and close the app, the setting must be saved.

As what I found online, there are some ways to save the user setting. Can someone provide me a step-by-step tutorial or a link about saving the user setting into the XML?

P.S. I have some Linq experience. Linq to XML method is preferable by me.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is a homework assignment requiring an XML file but this method is much easier than a custom XML solution and is built into the WPF application.

[Configuring Application/User Settings in WPF the easy way](http://geekswithblogs.net/mbcrump/archive/2010/06/17/configuring-applicationuser-settings-in-wpf-the-easy-way.aspx)

**P.S.**  Don't forget to call `.Save()` upon your setting changes!

Comment: well....thx for your suggestion. But i still go for the xml method. Thanks again C=